# Are questions about machine directives welcome here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Machine directives are standards that are transcribed into law, describing safety regulations for machinery builders/developers.

Examples of such standards are:

- Australian Standard AS4024 - Safeguarding of machinery.
- Canadian Standard CSA Z432-04 - Safeguarding of machinery.
- USA Standard NFPA 79 - Electrical standard for industrial machinery.
- European Standard IEC 60204 - Safety of machinery – Electrical equipment of machines

Standards like these end up in directives like the European Union (EU) Machinery Directive (2006/42/EC).

The standards themselves are not technically laws, but the law specifies you have to conform to it (just like building codes). And honestly, they're more legalese than technical in nature. *However*, there's a good possibility some technical knowledge is required to answer them.

Would questions about these standards and/or directives be welcome here? If so, are there any specific hazards to keep in mind when asking questions about such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

If the question is legal in nature rather than technical.

For example, [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41582/would-towels-under-floorboards-for-sound-insulation-be-considered-an-unaccepta) question is a marginal fit for this site but the accepted answer deals with it correctly. The technical non-compliance is obvious so this engages the legal consequences. If the technical issue were central or more of an issue the question should have been closed.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you'll get more useful answers if you're able to tailor the questions to minimize the technical aspect and maximize the legal one.